# Diffable datasource performance issues with > 20K rows

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, diffabledatasource, uitableviewdiffabledatasource

I run into performance issues with the diffable data source when having a larger data set, around 22,000 items. I am surprised that applying the snapshot takes so much time when animation is ON. See the code section:

```
let shouldAnimate = tableView.numberOfSections != 0
apply(snapshot as NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, NSManagedObjectID>, animatingDifferences: shouldAnimate)
```

Note: there is a good resource [here](https://www.jessesquires.com/blog/2021/07/08/diffable-data-source-behavior-changes-and-reconfiguring-cells-in-ios-15/) by Jesse Squires:

My questions is, am I missing something or diffable data source cannot handle this any faster given that applying a snapshot is an O(n) operation?

Turning off animation, same as `reloadData`, would somewhat help.

The sample code was setup based on [this](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/diffable-data-sources-core-data/) article by the awesome [SwiftLee](https://www.avanderlee.com/).

[image]

Please see the sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hBMuuM1CbpP1gupbXm4JIQyaX2JP0zf9/view?usp=sharing).

Sample video [here](https://youtu.be/ZX_XQQCQORA).

Update (September 2nd, 2021): A good Twitter discussion [here](https://twitter.com/freak4pc/status/1433139838841200640).

Sidenote:
The sample app can be improved by not setting the `fetchBatchSize` since the request is used with a `NSFetchedResultsController`. See [link](https://www.donnywals.com/preventing-unwanted-fetches-when-using-nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-fetchbatchsize/).

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 15 we now have [Apply SnapShot Using ReloadData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource/3804469-applysnapshotusingreloaddata).

It's a lot faster than apply snapshot if you are replacing data and dont care about animations